# Apache - MaxClients

Tags: apache

I'm setting up a new Apache server.

If I set the **MaxClients** definition to, let's say, one - does it then block anyone who else who tries to connect to my Apache server except for that one person?

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you'll get only one request handled by apache, if you put a quite long KeepAlive Timeout the process will be held for that amount of time by the user. The 2nd user will get his request done by apache only when the first one is finished (or when the keepAlive Timeout ends if the request is in keepAlive mode). So with a small KeepAlive setting, if the requests are fast to handle, you could have a lot of users, done one after the other, without knowing apache handles only one request in parallel.

If you make some activity in the first connection you may be able to block the 2nd request for a very long time.

Now, you should'nt consider it as a way to restrict access to one dedicated person, it's not a security feature. You rely on TCP/IP connections, if the connection breaks, then the 2nd user may get access to the server.